# Do FAA knowledge test endorsements have an implicit expiration date? If not, can I add one explicitly?

Tags: faa-regulations, logbook-endorsements, faa-knowledge-test

Many things in aviation have a 60-day window. For example, a graduation certificate from an approved part 141 course is valid for the purposes of a checkride for 60 days after the date of graduation.

Suppose I endorse an (otherwise fully qualified) student to take a private pilot knowledge test, but the student doesn't take the test for an extended period (because of illness, military deployment, or whatever).  Some amount of time later, the student appears at a testing center with the endorsement in hand.  **Is there a particular time limit beyond which a knowledge test endorsement is no longer valid?**

If not, **could I write the endorsement so that it includes a void date**?  Something like:

> I certify that Mr. Orville Wright has met the required training of blah blah and is prepared to take the private pilot knowledge exam. *This endorsement is valid until October 31 2017*.

Comment: Why add an exp date?

Comment: @acpilot - Because a student who's ready to take an exam in October 2017 is unlikely to still be ready in June 2019, but if there's no expiration date, they can still go.

Comment: I guess I just don't see the risk.

Comment: @acpilot, risk is one way to look at it, but if the instructor feels there should be a limitation, that's his choice. Probably a good thing to explain to the student, though.

Comment: As a CFI, I disagree.  It make no difference to me and only causes problems for the customer in the event that unforseen delays crop up in the course of training.  Life happens.  It's only a written test.

Comment: @acpilot - One of the criteria for renewing the certificate for a part 141 school is written exam pass rate. As an *instructor*, you're right, it makes no difference to you, but as a *chief* instructor with your school's renewal coming up later in the year, it might not be "only a written test" anymore.

Comment: @Steve V as a part 91 instructor, I do written endorsements as an AGI, rather than as a CFI, so I don't have to log results (14 CFR 61.189(b)(2))  Furthermore, you have a valid concern in that the material retention for a student will drop over time, unless ongoing study is done. Certainly over a  20 month period of time like in your comment.  As I said in my answer, you can always talk with your FSDO, but it is most likely you will hear what I did as explained in my answer.

Comment: I wondered about this myself so I asked the proctor at the CATS site where I take my exams. She couldn’t find anything that imposed a time limit. So tomorrow I am taking the Commercial Knowledge Test with an endorsement from 2001.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last that I looked into it, there were no expiration dates on written test endorsements by CFI and GI.  However, the FAA has made it clear many times that instructors are free to add conditions to endorsements.

For example, when I endorse a student for solo, I will put limitations like:
1.Prior phone call to instructor, 2. surface winds less than 14K, and within 45 deg of runway heading, 3.Five miles vis with VFR conditions.

Of course solo endorsements have implied expiration dates. But you could endorse J Pilot for a instrument written, and add "Endorsement expires Jan 1, 2018."

Since these things are vetted regionally, if you have any concerns, you can always call the FSDO and talk with an Ops Inspector there.

I did that once when I signed a guy off for a Flight Review, and wanted a condition on the sign-off. The pilot agreed with the condition, and I ran it past the Safety Program Manager who was an Ops Inspector, and his words were, "Absolutely! Any restriction you think is appropriate is fine to add to the endorsement."  That was sometime ago, but I have no indication that the policy/latitude has changed.

Comment: Just an afterthought...as a CFI one needs to log written test results.  So that could also be a reason to not leave open ended written test endorsements.  I simply sign of all written test exams with my ground instructor certificate, which has no such log requirement.